# Length of triangle edges

Tags: geometry

[image]

X is the middle of AB

Z is the middle of AC

Y is the middle of BC

is AX always equal to ZY?

Comment: That's what Thales' theorem asserts.

Comment: Isn't Thales' theorem the one about right triangles having their circumcenter on the hypotenuse?

Comment: The triangle $\triangle XYZ$ is the [mediai triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_triangle) of $\triangle ABC$, a half-scale copy. So yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Because of Thales theorem

$AZYX$ and $XZYB$ are parallelograms so $ZY=XB$ and $ZY=AX$ implies $ZY=\frac12 AB$

[image]